# Search methods in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm working on extracting patients info in FHIR server however, I've came across two types of searching methods that were somewhat different. What is the difference between the search method of

```
Bundle bundle = client.seach().forResource(DiagnosticReport.class)
                .
                .
```

and

```
GET [base]/DiagnosticReport?result.code-value- 
quantity=http://loinc.org|2823-3$gt5.4|http://unitsofmeasure.org|mmol/L
```

It's very confusing as it seemed that there isn't much that is mentioned about these two search methods. Can i achieve the same level of filtering with the first method compared to the url method?

Answer (score 1):

The first is how to perform a search using the Java reference implementation.  The latter explains what the actual HTTP query looks like that hits the server (and also specifies some additional search criteria).  Behind the scenes the Java code in the first example is actually making an HTTP call that looks similar to the second example.  The primary documentation in the FHIR specification deals with the HTTP call.  The reference implementations work differently based on which language they are and are documented outside the FHIR specification on a reference implementation by reference implementation basis.